# Request: apply the `default` code syntax highlighting to all tags by default

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

## Background

Stack Exchange allows to assign a code language syntax to every tag. It will then use that language to highlight the code of appropriately tagged questions.

There is a `default` syntax highlighting option that effectively acts as auto-detect and attempts to highlight code based on its contents.

Currently, all tags (apart from [the ones we explicitly assigned language hints to](https://sitecore.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202/default-syntax-highlighting-for-tags-we-need-your-input)) have `<none>` set as language. This means that code will not be highlighted, unless we modify the tag, or there's a [language hint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108) manually defined in the text of a question.

## Request

Please make the `default` code language syntax to be the default for all tags instead of `<none>`.

There will be almost no questions with incorrect syntax highlighting after this. We'll apply a couple of manual changes for several questions after the request is fulfilled.

Comment: Done. Let me know if there are any problems. (Not that I anticipate any.)

Comment: @JonEricson Thanks a lot, Jon! It seems to be working really well.